# Install and select libatlas in Fedora-23

Tags: fedora, software-installation, shared-library

So, in Ubuntu, to install libatlas, one does:

```
sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base
```

and then

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3
```

and then one picks one of the various `libblas.so.3` options shown there.

Likewise, doing:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3
```

allows one to pick on of the various available options for `liblapack.so.3`.

Now, my question is how does one do the same thing in Fedora-23?
For starters, I *think* (is this correct?)  that to install atlas, 
one does:

```
sudo dnf install atlas-devel
```

does this install atlas? And is there (as in ubuntu) a way to select which `liblapack.so.3` and `libblas.so.3` ones uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Fedora 23 :
There is no blas or lapack in atlas-3* / atlas-devel, or in atlas-sse* / atlas-sse*-devel.

atlas-sse2-static, atlas-sse3-static provides /usr/lib*/atlas-sse*/{libatlas.a,  **libcblas.a**, **libf77blas.a**, **liblapack.a**}.

And : atlas-sse2-static, atlas-sse3-static→ No entries to /etc/alternatives/ (scripts.log).

---